# Reduce/remove the gap between two table cells? in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html-table

I want to  make the img and text below as close as possible, but I'm having difficulties doing so..
[image]

CSS for style on container :

```
const style = {
    height: '100%',
    top: '0px',
    left: '0%',
    width:'12%',
    position: 'fixed',
    color: 'rgb(30 215 96)',
    textAlign: 'center',
    background: 'rgb(40, 40, 40)'
 };
```

```
<Container style={style}>
<Table>
 <TableRow>
               <TableCell style={{width: '3px'}}>{track.trackCover,
               <img
                        class="cover"
                        alt="cover"
                        style={{ width: "50px", height: "50px" }}
                        src={track.trackCover}
                      />}</TableCell>
              <TableCell style={{width: '3px'}} >{track.name}, {track.artists}</TableCell>
             
            </TableRow>
       </Table>
    </Container>
```

I've currently got it set  up like this. The width in the table cell reduces it as close as the img above, however I want them basically touching.. I've tried -3px and even 0. But They seem to make it more distant.  Can someone help me identify what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Try with  add and  decreasing margin left value to the text eg: `margin-left:-5px`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Both increasing and decreasing margin left don't affect anything.

Comment: try with padding

Comment: oh okay welcome:)